# How do I parse json-object using python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a json object and having problems.

```
import json

record= '{"shirt":{"red":{"quanitity":100},"blue":{"quantity":10}},"pants":{"black":{"quantity":50}}}'
inventory = json.loads(record)
#HELP NEEDED HERE
for item in inventory:
    print item
```

I can figure out how to obtain the values. I can get keys. Please help.

Comment: If you can get keys, then you can certainly get the values. That example shows a nested dictionary. Loop through it, checking if the value is a dictionary before displaying it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You no longer have a JSON object, you have a Python [**dictionary**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Iterating over a dictionary produces its keys.

```
>>> for k in {'foo': 42, 'bar': None}:
...   print k
... 
foo
bar
```

If you want to access the values then either index the original dictionary or use one of the methods that returns something different.

```
>>> for k in {'foo': 42, 'bar': None}.iteritems():
...   print k
... 
('foo', 42)
('bar', None)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import json

record = '{"shirts":{"red":{"quantity":100},"blue":{"quantity":10}},"pants":{"black":{"quantity":50}}}'
inventory = json.loads(record)

for key, value in dict.items(inventory["shirts"]):
    print key, value

for key, value in dict.items(inventory["pants"]):
    print key, value
```